# Fire jQuery function on a `<li>` that is appended dynamically

Tags: jquery, dynamic, live

I need to run a jQuery function on any new `<li>` that is appended/added to a `<ul>` list, right when it is added. We might start out with:

```
<ul id="my">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

After some event on the page but without page-refresh, we have this:

```
<ul id="my">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li> <!-- Added dynamically -->
</ul>
```

I want to run a jQuery function on this (and again on any future) new `<li>`.

With the `.on` function I can catch any change that happens to the wrapping `<ul>`:

```
jQuery('body').on('DOMSubtreeModified', 'ul#my', function() {
  ...
});
```

How do I tweak this to catch not any change inside the `<ul>`, but to catch the specific `<li>` which is being added? Something along the lines of:

```
jQuery('body').on('DOMSubtreeModified', 'NEW_LI', function() {
  NEW_LI.css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

Comment: Why not do it where you add it?

Comment: @mplungjan The scenario is that I use MathJax to typeset the page initially to have math formatting, and in a chat window I wish to run MathJax again on only those messages that are being added to the chat window.

Comment: `DOMSubtreeModified` is deprecated in favor of [the `MutationObserver` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Your first step should be to use MutationObserver for new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`MutationObserver` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is the recommended way to watch DOM modifications. It's easy to integrate, too.

Be sure to inspect the `mutation` variable, to get an idea what kind of information you can access.

```js
function createObserver(callback) {
    return new MutationObserver(function (mutationRecords) {
        mutationRecords.forEach(callback);
    });
}

$("ul").each(function () {
    var obs = createObserver(function (mutation) {
        $(mutation.addedNodes).css("background-color", "yellow");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(mutation.addedNodes).css("background-color", "");
        }, 1000);
    });
    obs.observe(this, { childList: true });
});


// ---------------------------------------------------------------

setTimeout(function () {
    $("<li>New content appears!</li>").appendTo("ul#my");
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="my">
  <li>existing content</li>
  <li>existing content</li>
  <li>existing content</li>
</ul>
```